# How to get extreme points from UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have this image that contains few objects with different color. The background of image is white color.

I need to found top left point and bottom right point to crop image with the objects bounces.

The image below show just one gray object (exclude small dots and labels) that I need to crop, but at first I need to get these extreme points.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Extract the bitmap data from the image
unsigned char* imageData= [self extractImageDataForImage:self.image];

// Iterate through the matrix and compare pixel colors

for (int i=0; i< height; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<width*4; j+=4){ // assuming we extracted the RGBA image, therefore the 4 pixels, one per component
         int pixelIndex= (i*width*4) + j;
         MyColorImpl* pixelColor= [self colorForPixelAtIndex:pixelIndex imageData:imageData];
         if( [self isColorWhite:pixelColor] ){
              // we're not interested in white pixels
         }else{
             // The reason not to use UI color a few lines above is so you can compare colors in the way you want. 
             // You can say that two colors are equal if the difference for each component is not larger than x. 
             // That way you can locate pixels with equal color even if they are almost the same color.

             // Let's say current color is yellow

             // Get the object that contains the info for the yellow drawable

             MyColoredObjectInformation* info= [self.coloredObjectDictionary objectForKey:pixelColor.description];

             if(!info){
                 //it doesn't exist. So lets create it and map it to the yellow color

                 info= [MyColoredObjectInformation new];
                 [self.coloredObjectDictionary setObject:info forKey:pixelColor.description];
             }
             // get x and y for the current pixel

             float pixelX= pixelIndex % (width*4);
             float pixelY= i;

             if(pixelX < info.xMin)
                  info.xMin= pixelX;

             if(pixelX > info.xMax)
                  info.xMax= pixelX;

             if(pixelY > info.yMax)
                  info.yMax= pixelY;

             if(pixelY < info.yMin)
                  info.yMin= pixelY;
         }
    }
}

// don't forget to free the array (since it's been allocated dynamically in extractImageForDataForImage:]
free(imageData];
```

Don't forget to set xMin, xMax, yMin and yMax to appropriate values for each object

```
@implementation MyColoredObjectInformation

-(id)init{
    if( self= [super init]){
         self.xMin= -1;
         self.xMax= INT_MAX;
         self.yMin= -1;
         self.yMax= INT_MAX;
    }
 return self;
 }
```

One thing that might happen when converting the image to the data array is that pixels don't go top-> bottom & left-> right. Usually image can be rotated when you convert it to CGImage. In that case, you'll just have different formula for pixelIndex, pixelX and pixelY.

At the end, just iterate through the values of `self.coloredObjectDictionary` and for each color you will have two points that represent the rect around the object p1(xMin, yMin) and p2(xMax, yMax)